# How to clear out `number of unconfirmed transactions exceeds ETH_MAX_QUEUED_TRANSACTIONS. WARNING`

Tags: chainlink

I have a Chainlink node and I'm hitting this error:

```
number of unconfirmed transactions exceeds ETH_MAX_QUEUED_TRANSACTIONS. WARNING: Hitting ETH_MAX_QUEUED_TRANSACTIONS is a sanity limit and should never happen under normal operation. This error is very unlikely to be a problem with Chainlink, and instead more likely to be caused by a problem with your eth node's connectivity. Check your eth node: it may not be broadcasting transactions to the network, or it might be overloaded and evicting Chainlink's transactions from its mempool. Increasing ETH_MAX_QUEUED_TRANSACTIONS is almost certainly not the correct action to take here unless you ABSOLUTELY know what you are doing, and will probably make things worse: cannot create transaction; too many unstarted transactions in the queue (250/250). WARNING: Hitting ETH_MAX_QUEUED_TRANSACTIONS is a sanity limit and should never happen under normal operation. This error is very unlikely to be a problem with Chainlink, and instead more likely to be caused by a problem with your eth node's connectivity. Check your eth node: it may not be broadcasting transactions to the network, or it might be overloaded and evicting Chainlink's transactions from its mempool. Increasing ETH_MAX_QUEUED_TRANSACTIONS is almost certainly not the correct action to take here unless you ABSOLUTELY know what you are doing, and will probably make things worse
```

What is the best action item to take to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This means, that there are more than `ETH_MAX_QUEUED_TRANSACTIONS` in the `eth_txes` table in the psql database. You can do a few things, but it's important to know what they all do.

### Delete the unstarted txes

1. Log into your database:
   `psql <DATABASE_URL_STRING`using a [psql client](https://blog.timescale.com/blog/how-to-install-psql-on-mac-ubuntu-debian-windows/)
2. Run the following:

```
DELETE FROM eth_txes WHERE state = 'unstarted';
```

Or find all the stuck transactions with:

```
select * from eth_txes;
```

Note, this will drop all transactions in the memepool of your node.

### Bump up `ETH_MAX_QUEUED_TRANSACTIONS`

1. Edit your `.env` with:

```
ETH_MAX_QUEUED_TRANSACTIONS=<SOME_NUMBER_MORE_THAN_250>
```

2. Restart your node

This won't drop any transactions, but it'll just bump up how many can be "in flight" at once. Usually this isn't the right move.